# Postgres - Taking Greatest of columns created from JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a JSON column in a Postgres DB that has keys of date of week and values of visits on that date. I want to get the max of the days and add it as a column next to the values for all of the days of week.

I have the below query which I thought could do it.  But I'm currently getting the error "column 'monday' does not exist"

Why doesnt monday exist after I extract it from the JSON? The inside query works fine and returns all the days and there respective values as I expected (with columns Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday).  I thought it would be relatively easy to then query these columns and get the greatest.

```
SELECT Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday,
GREATEST(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) as MaxDay
FROM "VisitData"
WHERE
    (SELECT 
        popularity_by_day ->> 'Monday' AS Monday,
        popularity_by_day ->> 'Tuesday' AS Tuesday,
        popularity_by_day ->> 'Wednesday' AS Wednesday,
        popularity_by_day ->> 'Thursday' AS Thursday,
        popularity_by_day ->> 'Friday' AS Friday
    FROM "VisitData")
```

UPDATE:

I now have this query after aliasing subquery:

````
    SELECT Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday,
    GREATEST(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) as MaxDay
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            popularity_by_day ->> 'Monday' AS Monday,
            popularity_by_day ->> 'Tuesday' AS Tuesday,
            popularity_by_day ->> 'Wednesday' AS Wednesday,
            popularity_by_day ->> 'Thursday' AS Thursday,
            popularity_by_day ->> 'Friday' AS Friday
    FROM "VisitData") AS visits
    ```

This gives me the structure of the output im expecting but the results are inconsistent.

For example row 1 in the result
Monday = 5
Tuesday = 89
Wednesday = 95
Thursday = 120
Friday = 102
MaxDay = 95  (why not 120)

And for row 2
Monday = 329
Tuesday = 350
Wednesday = 439
Thursday = 397
Friday = 314
MaxDay = 439 (This is correct)
````

Comment: I think you need to remove the part `"VisitData" WHERE` and then alias the subquery.

Comment: `WHERE` needs a boolean expression not a sub-query

Comment: Hi - can you each please elaborate? It seems like they are opposite recommendations? Or is it two ways to get to same end?  I thought sub query was a clean way to do it - but maybe im missing something. thx much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.Monday, v.Tuesday, v.Wednesday, v.Thursday, v.Friday,
       GREATEST(v.Monday, v.Tuesday, v.Wednesday, v.Thursday, v.Friday) as MaxDay
FROM "VisitData" vd CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT vd.popularity_by_day ->> 'Monday' AS Monday,
             vd.popularity_by_day ->> 'Tuesday' AS Tuesday,
             vd.popularity_by_day ->> 'Wednesday' AS Wednesday,
             vd.popularity_by_day ->> 'Thursday' AS Thursday,
             vd.popularity_by_day ->> 'Friday' AS Friday
     ) v;
```

Comment: thanks for this - i get a new error now. 

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 4:      (VALUES (vd.popularity_by_day ->> 'Monday' AS Monday,

Can you elaborate what this approach is doing?

Comment: @matthewmturner . . . That should be `SELECT` rather than `VALUES`, so the aliases are inline.

Comment: Thx - that generates results.  However, I still run into the same issue that I raised in my update (which may now be getting out of the scope of my original question).  But the greatest is not consistently returning the greatest of the 5 columns.  Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesnt.  Example in my update.   Do you think thats related to the join/subquery or how im using greatest?

Comment: @matthewmturner . .  If I had to guess, it is because the value are strings.  You probably just have to convert them to numbers.